# How to handle event bubbling in Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I implemented a toggle button for a list of items. To display the items and the toggle button, I run them through a loop given below.

```
renderRowValue = (values) => {
    const sourceId = values.id;
    const payload = {id: values.id, isActive: !values.isActive };
    return (
        <tr>
            <td key = {sourceId}>
                {values.name}
            </td>
            <td>
                <SwitchToggleButton
                    onChange={this.handleToggleChange(payload)}
                    defaultChecked={values.isActive}
                    label={"version2"}
                />
            </td>
        </tr>
    )
};
```

Then I call the function to display the value in the renderRowValue like this below:

```
<Grid xs={12} sm={12} md={10} className="shadow-border">
                <Row>
                    <Table striped bordered hover>
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Source</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        {values.map(this.renderRowValue)}
                        </tbody>
                    </Table>
                </Row>
            </Grid>
```

But the main issue is that when I toggle a button on the value of the others changes.For example, I turn the first item on, then everything else turns on automatically, the same for when I turn it off.

The function to handle toggle switch can be found below:

```
handleToggleChange =(values) => {
    this.props.dispatch(values.isActive(values));
};
```

Please how can I fix this issue to just turn it on for the first item without affecting the rest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I've done it trying to stick as close to your code as possible without actually seeing all of your code.

https://gist.github.com/leslie-alldridge/5ffd25cfbd48c3134495b2245aa9d7ad

Answer (score 1):

assuming the `handleToggleChange` is in the same class as your component.

Update it so that it's a `closure`

```
handleToggleChange = (payload) = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    this.props.dispatch(values.isActive(payload));
};


// renderRowValue 

<SwitchToggleButton
  onChange={this.handleToggleChange(payload)}
  defaultChecked={values.isActive}
  label={"version2"}
/>
```

Comment: With this approach, the compiler returns an error that payload is not defined